# Displaying products with a specific category jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, slice, catalog

I have products that I'm getting through an API and I tried creating a catalog with jQuery.  I'm using two different requests to get two different product categories.  I created my catalog on multiple pages thanks to the slice() function on jQuery like so :

```
var $el = $("#wrap > div");
var pageSize = 9;
var page = 1;

$el.slice(0, pageSize).css({display: 'block'});
$el.slice(pageSize, $el.length).css({display: 'none'});

function addSlice(num){
  return num + pageSize;
}

function subtractSlice(num){
  return num - pageSize;
}

var slice = [0, pageSize];
```

This is how I am displaying the products :

```
echo '<div id="wrap" class="wrap">';

foreach ($beds['moreProducts']['productWindow'] as $items)
{
        echo '<div class="bed_images" id="bed">';
        echo '<img data-enlargeable class="images" src=' . $items['mainImageUrl'] . '?f=xxs' . '/>';
        echo '<h2 class="img_title">' . $items['name'] . '</h2>';
        echo '<p class="img_price">' . $items['priceNumeral'] . ' ^b ' . '</p>';
        echo '<p class="img_description">' . $items['typeName'] . '</p>';
        echo '</div>';
}

foreach ($sofas['moreProducts']['productWindow'] as $items)
{
        echo '<div class="sofa_images" id="sofa">';
        echo '<img data-enlargeable class="images" src=' . $items['mainImageUrl'] . '?f=xxs' . '/>';
        echo '<h2 class="img_title">' . $items['name'] . '</h2>';
        echo '<p class="img_price">' . $items['priceNumeral'] . ' ^b ' . '</p>';
        echo '<p class="img_description">' . $items['typeName'] . '</p>';
        echo '</div>';
}
```

I created a selection selector with two options to display either one or the other. I first of all tried with the .hide method but it only hides the 9 items displayed, i then tried the .remove method which seemed like working but it let me empty pages until i reach the pages on which i had my items (for example i had pages 2-23 that were empty) So i'm kinda desperate to know how can i manage to only dislay the selected category ?